# apache 2.4 not able to resolve subdomains

Tags: apache, subdomain

I have a domain registered on GoDaddy (example.com) and is hosted on Virtual Private Server.
Apache configurations for www.example.com is working fine.
I created a subdomain (staging.example.com) and did necessary virtualhosts settings in Apache configuration, but it is not resolving.

I created an A Record for "staging" and pointed to the my server's IP address in the GoDaddy Zone files for my domain.

My VirtualHost settings are as follows. (This is defined in a separate virtualhosts.conf file and is included in the main httpd.conf)

`<VirtualHost "MyserverIPAddress":8080>
    ServerName staging.example.com
    ServerAlias staging.example.com
    ProxyRequests Off
    <Location />
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyPass http://example.com:8080/
        ProxyPassReverse http://example.com:8080/
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>`

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!
Sharad

Comment: _“but it is not resolving”_ – what does that mean, specifically? Does it not resolve properly when your client queries the DNS server? Or does the request reach your Apache, but that then doesn’t know what to do with it? Errors?

Comment: when i enter the url staging.example.com:8080 in the browser it keeps spinning and after some time gives 503 error. The request it seems isn't reaching the apache configuration for resolution. I have

Answer (score 0):

Resolved the problem as follows:

I was trying to run the staging sub-domain (staging.example.com) on port 8080. I changed it back to run it on port 80 and removed all the proxy related directives. I also removed the ServerAlias directive which was (staging.example.com).

I have the sub-domain now picking up files correctly as well.

Thanks!